# Select row data if other row data is matched

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have dataframe:

```
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
   df.head()

               title                    poster
     0       Toy Story       https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images...
     1       Jumanji         https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images...
```

I want to create a function which will take movie title as the input and return an return the poster link as output. I tried the following, but it is not working:

```
def function_to_return_link(movie_name):
     if df['title'].str.contains(movie_name).any():
            print('Movie present in df')
            out = df.loc[df['title'] == movie_name]
            print(out)
     else:
        print('Movie is not present')
```

It showing the output as:

```
function_to_return_link('Toy Story')

Movie present in df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [title, poster]
Index: []
```

Comment: you have a `pos` dataframe inside you function but on your example you save the data to `df`, it's much easier to help you if you provide a [mcve]. My blind suggestion is to be carefull with whitespace, it might be causing the empty dataframe since the names don't match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.loc[..., 'poster']` returns a pd.Series with your selected movie(s). Then, use `pd.Series.iat` to get the first value in the selection (by index). If the movie isn't present, then it raises an IndexError.

```py
def function_to_return_link(movie_name):
    posters = df.loc[df['title'].str.contains(movie_name), 'poster']
    try:
        link = posters.iat[0]
    except IndexError:
        print('Movie is not present')
    else:
        return link
```

Note that this doesn't account for duplicate entries (multiple entries). To deal with that, you could do the below (though it's arguably/perhaps less pythonic than try/except).

```py
def function_to_return_link(movie_name):
    posters = df.loc[df['title'].str.contains(movie_name), 'poster']
    if len(posters) > 1:
        print('Multiple hits')
    elif len(posters) == 0:
        print('Movie is not present')
    else:
        return posters.iat[0]
```

Comment: In the above example You have selected only single column, can I select multiple columns at a time and return it as an list or dictionary?

Comment: Yes, you can return with .iloc: e.g. `posters.iloc[0, [COLUMNS]]` or `poster.iloc[0, :]` for the whole row (giving you a Series). To convert, `ser.values` for a list-like np.ndarray (from which you can convert to list) and `ser.to_dict()` for dicts. `list(ser)` and `dict(ser)` are also possible but are much slower. e.g. for `ser = pd.Series(range(1000))`, `timeit.timeit('ser.to_dict()', globals={'pd': pd, 'ser': ser}, number=1000)` is only 0.5224s, while `timeit.timeit('dict(ser)', globals={'pd': pd, 'ser': ser}, number=1000)` is 11.8488s

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could do:

```
def function_to_return_link(movie_name):
    if movie_name in pos['title']:
        return pos.query("title == @movie_name")['poster']
    else:
        print('Movie is not present')
```